# Handling multiple type of errors

Tags: java, c++, error-handling, enums

Suppose I have two distinct libraries:

The first one is a Network library, and the second one an XML library.

Both libraries have its defined errors : NetworkError and XMLError enums.

Now I'm merging both libraries into one. It will receive an XML from network and handle its tags.

However any method can internally suffer of any kind of error, XMLError or NetworkError.
My library should not handle the errors and should forward them to its user.

Once my language is statticaly typed I can't return multiple types.

What is the best approach to solve this problem? Create a new enum which logically correspond to the union of both enums?

Exceptions are not an option.

Thank you.

Comment: Pick a language. It is rarely ever correct to tag a single question with two completely different languages.

Comment: I just want an overall view about the problem. I have to solve this in both java AND c++ because the error will occur in C++ and will be handled in Java. I'm using JNI.

Answer (score -1):

I think your approach would be the best method to solve the Issue, because the only other way would be to return a container of Enums, which would be pretty uncommon for a lib

Comment: This is more a comment, than an answer. Provide more information, why you think that his approach would be the best.

Comment: @Etixpp please don't answer the question which seems to be incomplete or inaccurate rather you comment your possible recommendation.

Comment: Ok sry, i am new to stackoverflow